# Python 3.x tkinter Drag and Drop preventing menu from being clickable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, drag-and-drop

Something about the drop_target_register() method seems to disable clicking the menubar until a file is dropped into the drop target. I would like to have the menubar functional regardless of whether or not there is a file in the drag and drop.

I'm running Python 3.6.4, and this is a simple tidbit of code that displays the problem.

```
from tkinter import *
from TkinterDnD2 import *

def drop(event):
    entry_sv.set(event.data)

root = TkinterDnD.Tk()

menubar = Menu(root)

menu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
menu.add_command(label="Exit", command=root.quit)
menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=menu)

root.config(menu=menubar)

entry_sv = StringVar()
entry_sv.set('Drop Here...')
entry = Entry(root, textvar=entry_sv)
entry.pack(fill=X)
entry.drop_target_register(DND_FILES)
entry.dnd_bind('<<Drop>>', drop)

root.mainloop()
```

In PyCharm 'drop_target_register' and 'dnd_bind' both display the message:

> "Unresolved attribute reference 'drop_target_register' for class
>   'Entry' This inspection detects names that should resolve but don't.
>   Due to dynamic dispatch and duck typing, this is possible in a limited
>   but useful number of cases. Top-level and class-level items are
>   supported better than instance items."

That said, the drag and drop works.

Comment: Are you trying to allow dragging objects to menu items? Or trying to handle two mice with separate cursors, where one is dragging an object and the other is pulling down a menu? Or trying to do keyboard menu navigation while the mouse is dragging an object? Or…?

Comment: Anyway, the answer is probably going to be the same for almost any answer. Tkinter is just a wrapper around Tk, which ultimately relies on your OS/window system for a lot of functionality. Anything that didn't make sense for a cross-platform abstraction in Tk 8.0 (that is, Classic Mac, Motif, and Windows 95) is probably not going to be there. And back in 1997, 2/3 of those platforms had menus that took over the entire event loop, and the lowest common denominator for drag&drop was very, very low. So I wouldn't be surprised if whatever it is you want is impossible.